# confirmation_url points to localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise

I am using Devise and omniauth for authentication in my rails app.
I have followed readme and put the following line in my production.rb :

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 
'http://morning-autumn-487.heroku.com' }
```

My mailer has the following code:

```
<%= link_to 'Confirm my account',confirmation_url(@user, :confirmation_token =>
@user.confirmation_token) %>
```

When I upload the app to heroku, the confirmation mail has the
following link for registration in the email :
http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=8TyGWQo6y...
Is there a setting that governs this host name ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok the issue was that - in setup_mail.rb there was a string :

```
ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] pointing to localhost:3000
```

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 7):

Try with

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'morning-autumn-487.heroku.com' }
```

Comment: Nopes, still getting link as : http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=_j2KgymYYP-a361z15qI

Comment: That's very strange, it works for me (also on Heroku). It also seems you have a development flag set somewhere, as it's showing port 3000 (the default development port). Are you sure you're not testing for a local instance by mistake?

Comment: can you try on : www.socl.in ? try signup and you will get the mail, that would give you the URL

Comment: So for 'www.socl.in' should my production.rb look like :   config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'www.socl.in' } ?

Comment: Ok, further grepping my source code, I found that in setup_mail.rb I had the string: ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] pointing to localhost:3000. Pushed the app to heroku after changing this, will update the results